# Replace and increment letters and numbers with awk or sed

Tags: bash, perl, nginx, awk, sed

I have a string that contains

```
fastcgi_cache_path /var/run/nginx-cache15 levels=1:2 keys_zone=MYSITEP:100m inactive=60m;
```

One of the goals of this script is to increment *nginx-cache* two digits based on the value find on previous file. For doing that I used this code:

```
# Replace cache_path

PREV=$(ls -t /etc/nginx/sites-available | head -n1) #find the previous cache_path number
CACHE=$(grep fastcgi_cache_path $PREV | awk '{print $2}' |cut -d/ -f4) #take the string to change
SUB=$(echo $CACHE |sed "s/nginx-cache[0-9]*[0-9]/&@/g;:a {s/0@/1/g;s/1@/2/g;s/2@/3/g;s/3@/4/g;s/4@/5/g;s/5@/6/g;s/6@/7/g;s/7@/8/g;s/8@/9/g;s/9@/@0/g;t a};s/@/1/g") #increment number
sed -i "s/nginx-cache[0-9]*/$SUB/g" $SITENAME #replace number
```

Maybe not so elegant, but it works.

The other goal is to increment last letter of all occurrences of *MYSITE**x*** (*MYSITEP*, in that case, should become MYSITE**Q**, after MYSITE**P**, etc. etc and once MYSITE**Z** will be reached add another letter, like MYSITE**AA**, MYSITE**AB**, etc. etc.

I thought something like:

```
sed -i "s/MYSITEP[A-Z]*/MYSITEGG/g" $SITENAME
```

but it can't works cause MYSITEGG is a static value and can't be used.
How can I calculate the last letter, increment it to the next one and once the last Z letter will be reached, add another letter?

Thank you!

Comment: Perl increments letters.  I suggest you're going to want `perl -p -e` solutions.  Add the tag if you're open to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perl's autoincrement will work on letters as well as digits, in exactly the manner you describe

We may as well tidy your `nginx-cache` increment as well while we're at it

I assume `SITENAME` holds the name of the file to be modified?

It would look like this. I have to assign the capture `$1` to an ordinary variable `$n` to increment it, as `$1` is read-only

```
perl -i -pe 's/nginx-cache\K(\d+)/ ++($n = $1) /e; s/MYSITE\K(\w+)/ ++($n = $1) /e;' $SITENAME
```

If you wish, this can be done in a single substitution, like this

```
perl -i -pe 's/(?:nginx-cache|MYSITE)\K(\w+)/ ++($n = $1) /ge' $SITENAME
```

Comment: Wow! This is a really nice solution! Everything in one line! It works like a charm. Thank you very much @Borodin!!

Answer (score 2):

Note: The **solution below is needlessly complicated**, because as [Borodin's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42528116/45375) demonstrates (and @stevesliva's comment on the question hinted at), **Perl *directly* supports incrementing letters alphabetically** in the manner described in the question, by applying the `++` operator to a variable containing a letter (sequence); e.g.:

```
$ perl -E '$letters = "ZZ"; say ++$letters'
AAA
```

The solution below *may* still be of interest as an annotated showcase of how Perl's power can be harnessed from the shell, showing techniques such as:

- use of `s///e` to determine the replacement string with an expression.
- splitting a string into a character array (`split //, "...."`)
- use of the `ord` and `chr` functions to get the codepoint of a char., and convert a(n incremented) codepoint back to a char.
- string replication (`x` operator)
- array indexing and slices:

  - getting an array's last element (`$chars[-1]`)
  - getting all but the last element of an array (`@chars[0..$#chars-1]`)

---

A `perl` solution (in effect a re-implementation of what `++` can do directly):

```sh
perl -pe 's/\bMYSITE\K([A-Z]+)/
  @chars = split qr(), $1; $chars[-1] eq "Z" ? 
    "A" x (1 + scalar @chars)
    :
    join "", @chars[0..$#chars-1], chr (1 + ord $chars[-1])
/e'  <<'EOF'
...=MYSITEP:...
...=MYSITEZP:...
...=MYSITEZZ:...
EOF
```

yields:

```
...=MYSITEQ:...    # P -> Q
...=MYSITEZQ:...   # ZP -> ZQ
...=MYSITEAAA:...  # ZZ -> AAA
```

You can use `perl`'s `-i` option to replace the input file with the result
(`perl -i -pe '...' "$SITENAME"`).

<sup>As Borodin's answer demonstrates, it's not hard to solve *all* tasks in the question using `perl` alone.</sup>

The `s` function's `/e` option allows use of a Perl *expression* for determining the replacement string, which enables sophisticated replacements:

- `$1` references the current `MYSITE` suffix in the expression.
- `@chars = split qr(), $1` splits the suffix into a character array.
- `$chars[-1] eq "Z"` tests if the last suffix char. is `Z`

  - If so: The suffix is replaced with all `A`s, with an additional `A` appended
    (`"A" x (1 + scalar @chars)`).
  - Otherwise: The last suffix char. is replaced with the following letter in the alphabet
    (`join "", @chars[0..$#chars-1], chr (1 + ord $chars[-1])`)

Comment: Replacing long runs of `grep | sed | awk | sed` with a single Awk script might be more easily within reach without learning a new language.  In general, if you are using Awk, you should need `grep` or `sed` in the same pipeline only very rarely and very sparingly.  But in this particular case, Perl seems like a good fit, because it supports the behavior the OP describes right out of the box.

Comment: You can also use the `..` operator with letters or zero-padded integers. (`'A'..'Z'`) There is a lot of string manipulation functionality hidden in operators where you might not expect it.

Comment: Thank you all guys for brilliant solution! I tried the @Borodin's one and it works perfectly!